# I can't subtract date with R

Tags: r, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongolite

I try to subtract datetime (round 30mins). I can do it with Robo3T. But when I try to do this I am getting an error like below.

"Error: cant $subtract a string from a Date"

I can do it with robo3T but I couldn't do it with R.

Here is my R script;

```
datas3$aggregate(paste('[
                       {"$group": {
                       "_id": {
                       "AssetConnectDeviceKey":"$AssetConnectDeviceKey",
                       "Time": {"$add": [
                       { "$subtract": [
                       { "$subtract": [
                       { "$add": [ "$CreateDate", ',1000 * 60 * 60 * 10 ,'] },
                       "new Date(0)" 
                       ]},
                       { "$mod": [
                       { "$subtract": [
                       { "$add": [ "$CreateDate",', 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10 ,'] }, 
                       "new Date(0)"
                       ]},',
                       1000 * 60 * 30,'
                       ]}
                       ]},
                       "new Date(0)"
                       ]}
                       },
                       "Longitude": { "$avg": "$Longitude" }, 
                       "Latitude": { "$avg": "$Latitude" }

                       }}]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lubridate package to achieve this.

```
minutesLeftToday <- 1440 - hour(time)*60 - minute(time)
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but this is not the answer I looking for.  This subtract does round CreateDate. For example; "2019-03-01T11:20:00.000Z" ---> "2019-03-01T11:30:00.000Z"